# Serial port emulation that works with QSerialPort

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port, tty, pty

So I need some sort of connected pseudo tty that mimics an actual pair of serial ports. That will make my application test way more easier. There is of course `socat` that works perfectly on Linux:

```
sudo socat PTY,link=/dev/ttyS10,crnl PTY,link=/dev/ttyS11,crnl
```

But for some reason, [`QSerialPort`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qserialport.html) and [`QSerialPortInfo`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qserialportinfo.html) refuse to list them as serial devices.

Any workaround to make `QSerialPortInfo` believe that my pty is an actual serial port will help me a lot.

Comment: maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49544318/using-linux-pseudoterminal-to-test-qserialport/49547001#49547001

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pseudo terminals is not a serial ports. Use the [tty0tty](https://github.com/freemed/tty0tty) project as a kernel module instead (it is supported by QSP{I}.